# ?: in Java: How to combine res and resString more rationally?

Tags: java

I want output(mix of double res and String resString) is assigned a single variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab3Task02_08 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("х = ");
        int x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("y = ");
        int y = in.nextInt();
        double arithm = (x+y)/2;
        double geom = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x*y));
        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        double res = x>y? arithm:geom;
        String resString = x>y? "Arithm.average = ":"Geom.average = ";
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        System.out.print(resString + res);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *I want output(mix of double res and String resString) is assigned a single variable.* - is really unclear. Could you edit your question and specify what you exactly are looking for? [`:?` is a ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), which has nothing to do with any *combination* of two (or more) values.

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code? If there is an error, what is it?

Comment: There is no error, just asked in order to clean extra lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
String format = "%s.average = %d";
String res = x > y
        ? String.format(format, "Arithm", arithm)
        : String.format(format, "Geom", geom);
```

— But, really, I question the logic of having two different averages conflated in this way in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to output two different values depending on the same condition. One of the option, it could be done with `String.format()`, `Double.compare()` and `x ? y : x`.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("х = ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("y = ");
    int y = scan.nextInt();

    double arithmetic = (x + y) / 2.;
    double geometric = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x * y));
    int res = Double.compare(arithmetic, geometric);

    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s average = %.2f\n",
            res > 0 ? "Arithmetic" : "Geometric",
            res > 0 ? arithmetic : geometric);
}
```

**Output:**

```
х = 3
y = 5
Arithmetic average = 4.00

х = -4
y = 3
Geometric average = 3.46
```

Comment: Not only does this not answer what OP is most likely asking (a more concise way to show the output; Konrad's answer does that by producing the same result with only one use of the ternary operator), it changes the behaviour of the code significantly, and won't produce the same output as OP's code for the same input.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand the question , is this what you want ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab3Task02_08 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("х = ");
        int x = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("y = ");
        int y = in.nextInt();
        double arithm = (x+y)/2;
        double geom = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x*y));
        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        double res = x>y? arithm:geom;
        String resString = x>y? "Arithm.average = ":"Geom.average = ";
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String combinedRes = resString + res;
        System.out.print(combinedRes);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This produces the same output as OP's code. The only change seems to be an unnecessary extra variable `combinedRes`.